# How to fill vertical space between two dynamic divs?

Tags: html, css

Assume the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <!-- dynamic height -->
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="overflow: scroll;">
            <!--
                contains actual content
                height should be whatever is left over
            -->
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- dynamic height -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

basically what I want is:

`main height = body height - (header height + footer height)`

The body and html height is 100%.

As both the height of `header` and `footer` are dynamic (will change very frequently), I need a dynamic way to set the height of `main`, i.e, I can't specify any of the heights in pixels or percentages.

There are indeed other similar questions, but I am not looking for a "floating/sticky footer", the `main` div *must* have the remaining height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST specify the height of the footer and the header.

You can use javascript on document ready to set the height of the footer, header and then the main div.

Then, use css like this :

```
#header{
  position: absolute;
  top: px;
  height: /*dynamically set by javascript*/;
  left: px;
  right: px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: /*dynamically set by javascript*/;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: /* set by javascript with height of footer */;
  top: /* set by javascript with height of header */;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm if I don't specify the height, and add new elements into the `header` and `footer` via. ajax, thus making it resize on its own, would it be possible to get the height of the `header`, `footer` and `body` via. javascript (or jquery), then calculate the the height of the `main` div like in my original post (possibly with added margins)?

Comment: you must do a javascript function which is called to refresh the height of the footer, header and main div each time a size has changed (ajax call, initial loading of the page). you can use jquery .height() method to calculate the height of the divs

Comment: why are you positioning things absolutely? if you are going to use javascript you don't need to do this - you just calculate the height that the main needs to be based on the height of the footer and header compared to the window

Comment: well it's to avoid clipping. If you don't do it, the footer will move from top to bottom before/after javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using css, you will need to use javascript or jquery

[Set a min-height on content container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836301/set-a-min-height-on-content-container)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be limiting the #main element to a specific height, as that is the only condition I can think of where you are going to use this. You should already know that the body element will automatically scale according to the header, main and body height, thus the equation you state in your question will always be true unless padding/margins are used. In this case, just use max-height:

```
#main {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

This limits the #main element to 100% height, or the full page.

I believe this isn't what you're looking for, thus maybe you would like to clarify a bit more on why you want to do so? We might be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this is not what I am looking for. I don't want my webpage to have scrollbars, as the `main` div will have that. The content of the `main` div will be populated via. ajax and endless scrolling. In this scenario the `main` div would have the scrollbars, but I could imagine adding multiple divs into the `main` div, which all will be populated with ajax, but in that case the `main` div wont have scrollbars, but the sub divs will.