# html/css content doesn't stretch

Tags: html, css

In my page I want content (red color in the page) stretch to the footer(yellow color) ... I can't find any way to fix this past 3 days. Please help me..

```
index.html

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
    <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my style.css

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

Comment: you will need to use javascript to achieve this

Comment: what should I do with javascript

Comment: this person was trying to achieve the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836301/set-a-min-height-on-content-container/13836477#13836477

Comment: The red content does stretch to the footer If the content's content is more there is need generate scroll. See this fiddle where I have filled the content with content. http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/Y6mBk/

Comment: yes I know but if there is for example one line the content has to stretch to footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a min-height to the #content css has such for example:

```
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height:600px;
}
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/DAQ7W/

Another trick is to make the #wrapper the same background-color as the #content. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The term you are searching for is a 'sticky footer' I think. In that case use this script I wrote:

**Html**

```
<div id="pagewrap">

    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {

    function positionFooter() {

        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var documentHeight = $('#pagewrap').height();

        if (windowHeight > ($('#content').height() + $('#header').height())) {
            var pagewrapHeight = windowHeight - $('#footer').height();
            $("#pagewrap").height(pagewrapHeight);
        }
    }

    positionFooter();
    $(window).resize(positionFooter)

});
```

**Css**

```
body { background: red; }
#header { text-align: center; height:100px; background: green; }
#content { text-align: center; height: 300px; background: red; }

#footer {
   position: relative;
   height: 35px;
   line-height: 35px; /* Height footer */
   text-align: center;
   clear:both;
   background: yellow;
   color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
}
```